# Can we port an Indian phone number for WhatsApp Business Api? If yes How?

Tags: twilio, whatsapp, twilio-api

I created a chatbot which I want to integrate with WhatsApp business api, What i want to do is port my indian phone number from which I can send messages to everyone? If I can do that please what is the process?

nn

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can find [the different options to bring your own phone number to WhatsApp in this support article](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360052171393-Can-I-activate-my-own-phone-number-for-WhatsApp-on-Twilio-). You can either transfer the number to Twilio, but that it'll ported out of your existing carrier, and SMS and calls will go to Twilio.
Or you can Bring your own number (BYON) which is in private beta, so you'll need to talk to sales to get access to the beta.